# Multiple Volley request after eachother?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, request, android-volley

Im making an android app that needs to get JSON data through HTTP request. The data to be retrieved can be pretty big (100-500mb). The backend is a REST api written in RESTER (https://github.com/moddity/Rester)

So the problem is: I Can only get 10.000 JSON objects at a time (approx 10 megabyte). I would like if possible, to request 10.000 objects, and if there is more data to be retrieved, ill request the next 10.000 objects, and so on.

Right now im using Volley with JSONArrayRequest

```
private void requestMeasurement(int id, int limit, int offset) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    String url = "http://10.201.201.10:888/index.php/ser" + id + "?limit=" + limit + "&offset=" + offsett;
    JsonArrayRequest jsObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsObjectRequest);
}
```

Hope someone can help. And sorry for any bad english :)

Update: Tried to call request again inside onResponse():

```
private void requestMeasurement(final int id, final int limit, final int offset) {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    String url = "http://10.201.201.10:888/index.php/ser" + id + "?limit=" + limit;
    JsonArrayRequest jsObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            if (response.length() >= limit) {

                requestMeasurement(id, limit, offset+limit);
            } else {
                Log.i("Completed = ", "true");
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsObjectRequest);
}
```

This results in crash due to out of memory, which i dont get why...

Comment: You can check the size of your response list in onResponse callback, and call the request method until the response list is less than 10.000

Comment: @darwin Think i get what you mean and tried if it worked, but now i run out of memory and crashes. I've updated the descriptipon.

Comment: may be you are storing this huge data in a array List (holding in runtime memory), which lead to OOM because of the limited memory space for indvidual application in android

Comment: I fixed it. Lowered the number of objects per request to < 8000 and now it works fine :)

Comment: good, try it on different android devices. because the heap memory for devices are different, try testing on a low configuration devices, all the best